# Maven Netbeans proxy

Tags: java, windows, maven, netbeans, proxy

I have just installed netbeans on my windows 7 computer.

This is the first time i have used netbeans!

I am trying to compile a program what is using maven to manage its dependencies.

The problem is i cant seem to compile the program as maven is unable to connect to the URL http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

**I can get to this directly using a web browser**

Now i am sure this is a proxy problem as i also have the same code on a Linux box and i can compile that, and i did have to setup the proxy.

I know maven has its own proxy setting in the `settings.xml` file and i have edited that with what i believe to be the correct details.

The settings file is in the root folder of my project.

I have also setup the proxy in Netbeans IDE (and pressing the test button works)

But i still cannot compile it on my windows box.

**So my question are**:

- How do I correctly set up the maven proxy when using netbeans?
- How can I check to see if my proxy setting are A) correct and B) being used!

Comment: from the command line, executing: `mvn help:effective-settings` you should see what settings is maven effectively using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out its very easy!

My problem is that the code was put on my hard drive as a simple HG repository.
This means that i had a settings.xml file but it was in the solution folder, along with my pom.xml.

To fix my problem you need to:

Go to the projects tab in Netbeans
Right click the Project Files
  Choose create settings.xml

This makes a new settings file in C:\Users\.m2

I then copied and pasted the content from my root settings.xml into this new settings.xml

And Bingo! it works.

I just need to remember to make changes to both settings files so that a working settings document can be saved into source control.

Comment: I don't see the option to create a new settings.xml, can you be more specific? Or is it enough to just copy the maven\conf\settings.xml to the .m2\?

Comment: Yes you should just be able to copy it to that location. good luck

Comment: but it still uses http protocol so i cant get plugin @PaulSpain

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same issue Win7/NetBeans/Maven.

Looks to me like Maven needs its own proxy settings and doesn't use the once which are set in NetBeans.

There's a settings.xml in a subdirectory where you installed NetBeans: e.g.  c:\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\conf

Don't forget to remove the surrounding comments from the proxy section.